# Polymer platinum-push-messaging in firefox

Tags: firefox, push-notification, polymer

I'm wondering if the polymer  element does or will work with Firefox eventually.

The official documentation is a bit dated and the offical demo broken. I could not find any answer to this question yet.

Here is what I know so far:

- The official plugin https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-push-messaging#requirements documentation stats "Push messaging is currently only available in Google Chrome."
- Firefox has catched up and does support https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2016/01/25/firefox-can-now-get-push-notifications-from-your-favorite-sites/  push notifications meanwhile.
- the official demo does not currently work for any browser (see caturday-post)

So what is the deal ? Should it work or is this roadmap ?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: firebase messaging seems to be an good alternative to those that like to subscribe to the firebase service. 

I also learned that platinum-push-messaging does work in firefox. It was just not in my case because of webcomponentsjs bug that does not allow push registration when triggered from within a custom element (https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/521)

It started to subscribe as soon I moved the code into the document root.

Comment: However its also important to understand that subscription in firefox will NOT register to GCM or Firebase. The subscription will registered to Mozillas push service instead. 

I had to store this detail together with the subscription information in my aggregation database so that my push service can trigger the correct  push url for my user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<platinum-push-messaging>` depends on Google Cloud Messaging, which has been replaced by [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). You should switch to [`<firebase-messaging>`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/firebase-messaging) for the new service.

https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm

> FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure, with new SDKs to make Cloud Messaging development easier.